# Elastic Beanstalk's Hostmanager fails to start Apache, slow EBS attaching

Tags: apache, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm setting up an Elastic Beanstalk instance to run a Grails app on Tomcat and serve the UI web pages with Apache. The web content is on a EBS volume which is attached and mounted on boot with an init.d script ([mountec2vol](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=25071)). Apache's DocumentRoot is on this volume, /mnt/data/www. My AMI image is based on the default Beanstalk 64bit-Tomcat7-linux image.

It seems that the Hostmanager can't start Apache because the EBS volume takes a while (5-20 sec) to attach. This is what I get in /opt/elasticbeanstalk/var/log/bluepill.log:

> W, [2012-09-19T18:06:15.366835 #1283]  WARN -- : [hostmanager:httpd] {:stdout=>"Starting httpd: [FAILED]\r\n", :stderr=>"Syntax error on line 293 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf:\nDocumentRoot must be a directory\n", :exit_code=>1}

Because of this I don't get the web server online, the health checks fail and the instance is terminated and recreated...

Can I configure the hostmanager to delay Apache start until the EBS volume is up? Is this the right way to attach+mount an EBS with an Elastic Beanstalk instance?

Or am I doing something unnecessarily difficult here...is there a more straightforward way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elastic Beanstalk is an EC2 instance and behaves the same way. Here's some discussion concerning the same issue you're having: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=304528#304528

If you wish to store your static content on EBS volume, then write some simple handler to your EBS-dependent service init scripts to check the mount volume availability before doing anything else.

The "cloud solution" might be to store your content to S3 and load it from there when needed, however. Then you wouldn't need separate EBS for storage.

Comment: Thanks, it seems that modifying init/boot would be the solution.